# Diff two classes fields names and structure

Tags: java, spring, reflection

## My task

Force two classes to have the same (or similar) field names (and their types)

#### Description

I have an entity and Data Transfer Objects (DTO).
**How do I force** that if someone adds / removes / changes a field in **entity**, a test will fail, so DTO class matches the entity class by fields names and if possible by fields structure.

```
class City {

    private String name;
    private CityDetails cityDetails;
    private Mayor mayor;
}

class Mayor {
    private String name;
    private LocalDate electionFrom;
    private LocalDate electionTo;
}

class CityDto {
    private String name;
    private CityDetailsDto cityDetails;
    private MayorDto mayor;
}

class MayorDto {
    private String name;
    // The client of the end-point of such DTO does not care about the mayor election.
}
```

CityDetails and CityDetailsDto can be different or not necessary. I would like to have their diff.

## Approaches

#### Using so called diff tool

Let's imagine a diff tool which has input parameters - two objects and output parameter - Map, where Diff is a structure oldValue, newValue. This tool returns difference between input arguments.

```
public Map<String, Diff> diff(final Object first, final Object second) {
    // This is implemented.
    return innerDiff(first, second, otherParameters); // 
}

public class Diff {
    private String oldValue;
    private String newValue;
    // getters, setters, constructor.
}

// To achieve this, we used Guava Plain map. It works well!
```

How do I achieve the same for classes. I want to diff two classes and have their fields as difference.

```
public Map<String, FieldDiff> diff(Class<?> type1, Class<?> type2) {
    // How?
}
```

One idea is to use reflection and iterate though all fields of the class.

#### How about using toString and compare?

As an alternative, we define `toString()` methods in both and then compare.
How to do that if some fields are missing?

#### Serialize into JSON

Similar to the previous one, but serializing both objects into JSON and then compare their classes by json field names. However, if our entity have already annotation `DoNotSerializeNulls` with is equal to `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`, then how to do that?

## References

https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

Comment: If two of your classes have exactly the same structure, why have two classes at all?

Comment: One is DTO used for passing the object to client (HTTP or message broker, etc), and entity is for storing in the database.

Comment: Good question. First of all, I would check how the existing (https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application) DTO mappers work. I am pretty sure most of them do it with reflection.

Comment: I get that. But if they are exactly the same, you might as well have only one of them and ditch the other.